# Use strict throws up an error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code that enables me to scroll to a position on my webpage. However when I Use Strict, I get the following error:

TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'refElement.position().top')
(anonymous function) main:34

ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $target
(anonymous function) main.js:17

Please can someone explain why it doesn't work when I use strict and does when I comment it out? How do I get it to work?

Thanks

Code:

```
    'use strict';
    $(document).ready(function() {

    $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);

    //smoothscroll
    $('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(document).off("scroll");

        $('a').each(function () {
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        })
        $(this).addClass('active');

        var target = this.hash,
            menu = target;
        $target = $(target);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            'scrollTop': $target.offset().top+2
        }, 500, 'swing', function () {
            window.location.hash = target;
            $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);
        });
    });


});

function onScroll(event){
    var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
    $('#menu-center a').each(function () {
        var currLink = $(this);
        var refElement = $(currLink.attr("href"));
        if (refElement.position().top <= scrollPos && refElement.position().top + refElement.height() > scrollPos) {
            $('#menu-center ul li a').removeClass("active");
            currLink.addClass("active");
        }
        else{
            currLink.removeClass("active");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Do you know what `"use strict";` does? The whole point is to find errors.

Comment: try using `var $target` ... error is telling you that

Comment: What part of the error message don't you understand?

Comment: `var refElement = $(currLink.attr("href"));` - looks wrong - should just be `var refElement = currLink.attr("href")`

Comment: If any of the answers was helpful, please accept one of them.

Answer (score 2):

Your `var` declaration has a semicolon instead of a comma in it:

```
    var target = this.hash,
        menu = target;
    $target = $(target);
```

Should be:

```
    var target = this.hash,
        menu = target,
        $target = $(target);
```

Because that assignment to `$target` was not part of the `var` statement, it represented an assignment to an implicit global variable. That's not allowed in "strict" mode.

Answer (score 0):

Your `refElement` is a string (because you assigned a `href` attribute of `currLink` to it) and then you're trying to call `position()` method on it. Maybe you meant `currLink.position().top + currLink.height()`?